# HoverTool problems, bokeh. Shows "???" when signs (/, -) or special letters (æ,ø,å) are given

Tags: python, bokeh, interactive

I am trying to build a stacked barchat in bokeh over the different tree types in the different districts in Copenhagen. I have succeded in building a chart but also want it to include a HoverTool. My code is as seen below:

```
p = figure(x_range = districtName,plot_width = 900, plot_height=400, 
           title='Tree pr. district',toolbar_location= None)

# Stacked bar chart
renderers = p.vbar_stack(stackers=treeName,x='bydelsnavn',source=temp,
            width=0.5, color = colornames)

# Add the hover tool
for r in renderers:
    tree = r.name
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ("%s" % tree, "@%s" % tree)
    ], renderers = [r])
    p.add_tools(hover)

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Copenhagen city cistricts'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Tree counts'

show(p)
```

The hovertool works fine for the treeNames whichs do not have the danish letters 'ø', 'æ' or 'å' in them or a sign like '/' or '-'. For example for the `treeName` `Kirsebær/blomme` the hover tool shows `???ær/blomme`. So I am assuming it is because of the wierd letters and signs.

Below are the `districtName` and a bit of the `treeName`.

```
districtName = ['Vesterbro-Kongens Enghave', 'Indre By', 'Nørrebro', 'Valby',
       'Vanløse', 'Bispebjerg', 'Brønshøj-Husum', 'Amager Øst',
       'Østerbro', 'Amager Vest']
treeName = ['Lind', 'Kirsebær/Blomme', 'Tjørn', 'Robinie',
       'Kastanie', 'Valnød', 'Hestekastanie', 'Poppel', 'Ask', 'Eg',
       'Løn', 'Platan', 'Avnbøg', 'Røn', 'Skyrækker', 'Tretorn',
       'Trompetkrone', 'Pil', 'Tulipantræ', 'Hassel', 'Birk', ........
```

How can I solve this problem? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the values in `{}`:

```py
("%s" % tree, "@{%s}" % tree)
```

Comment: Does that solve encoding problems? Is it a bokeh thing?

Comment: What encoding problems? They are not mentioned in the OP. And yes, `{}` is a Bokeh thing, specific for `HoverTool`.

Comment: okay `:)` OP mentions it might have to do with the non-ASCII characters, that's why my immediate thought was Encoding Trouble. Let's see if this resolves the issue for the OP.

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot @EugenePakhomov that solved the problem! :D